# Interacting with page objects on single page app

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios, calabash-android

I am attempting to interact with an element on the page that is underneath another element, but hidden. The calabash query returns the correct element. Tap appears to interact with the element, as I get no error thrown at me and the page element is returned. However, I can physically touch the element on the app with my finger and it works.

Is there a way to reference some kind z index, or alternative way to interact with the element?

Note: Calabash 2.0.0.pre4 with hybrid app(ionic)

Thanks

Sorry, the element I am trying to interact with IS visible.
Here is my Query:

```
query "webView css:'#btn_get_a_quote'"
[
    [0] {
             "center" => {
            "X" => 186.80419921875,
            "Y" => 538.7015104293824
        },
            "webView" => "<UIWebView: 0x154e6ed70; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x154e6d8c0>>",
           "nodeName" => "LI",
                 "id" => "btn_get_a_quote",
        "textContent" => "\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\tGet a Quote\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t",
              "class" => "btn-icon in",
               "rect" => {
                   "x" => 186.8042,
              "height" => 67.1875,
                   "y" => 538.7015,
               "width" => 67.1875,
                "left" => 126.40625,
                 "top" => 426.69195556640625,
            "center_y" => 538.7015,
            "center_x" => 186.8042
        },
           "nodeType" => "ELEMENT_NODE"
    }
]
```

Here is my tap:

```
tap "webView css:'#btn_get_a_quote'"
Getting: http://iphone6-27.local:37265/map {}
[
    [0] {
             "center" => {
            "X" => 186.80419921875,
            "Y" => 538.7015104293824
        },
            "webView" => "<UIWebView: 0x155534d90; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x15554d470>>",
           "nodeName" => "LI",
                 "id" => "btn_get_a_quote",
        "textContent" => "\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\tGet a Quote\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t",
              "class" => "btn-icon in",
               "rect" => {
                   "x" => 186.8042,
              "height" => 67.1875,
                   "y" => 538.7015,
               "width" => 67.1875,
                "left" => 126.40625,
                 "top" => 426.69195556640625,
            "center_y" => 538.7015,
            "center_x" => 186.8042
        },
           "nodeType" => "ELEMENT_NODE"
    }
]
```

Tapping the element should take you to another page, and works when I physically do it.

Comment: How are you accessing the element you want to tap? Are you using id or index? In my experience Calabash works smoothly when the element is visible but when elements are hidden, you have to specifically access it by id or index.

Comment: No z index in Calabash though. Calabash is a UI testing tool. You will not need to access hidden elements in UI as they were hidden for a purpose. If it is not visible, accessing it will go against the UI automation testing paradigm.

Comment: I am using the query/tap command as such, an ios example: query "webView css:'#btn_log_in'" and the element is visible on the screen.

Comment: A quick update, I switched phones(started on iphone 5s - iOS 7.1, now using iphone6, iOS 9.1) and the new phone was able to touch one of the elements I was unable to interact with. I will post more as I find out more.

Comment: Another update, I switched to an Samsung S5, running 5.0, and had no issues interacting with page elements.

Answer (score 0):

> I am attempting to interact with an element on the page that is underneath another element, but hidden

In your comment you say the element is visible on the screen.  What do you mean by hidden?

> "webView css:'#btn_log_in'"

Is that the query? If not, can you paste the *actual* query?  A screenshot might be helpful as well.

As for your problem, have you seen the [WebView API](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/06-WebView-Support)?  Maybe an xpath or javascript query could help you?